# Why is my adult dog's coat changing color?

Tags: dogs

My 9 year old Yorkshire terrier was born with gray coat. Almost overnight, she is turning brown in her face and spot on her back. She has been spayed since 6 months. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is an absolutely normal thing and is a common change as a result of aging. I have a female German shepherd who came in at three months completely black, she is now five years old and there is almost no black left on her. In fact after every "shedding season" the new coat that grows back has a slightly different color from the last,  and this is completely normal and healthy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common thing, usually happens from sun bleaching. Does your girl spend a lot of time outdoors or in the sun?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a natural process and part of growth .. same thing happened to my Indian Female dog who was white and brown .. but lately she has many black spots which eventually turn into brown and finally her brown color is overshadowing the white one. I consulted a vet he says its okk.